# Django advice making views for ManyToMany model fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

i have 3 models having 2 manytomany relationship fields... and now i must to make the views.py function and the template. I want to do the template similary with what I have generated in django admin but i don t know how..

I will post models.py structure

```
from app_name.models import Person, Admin
from another_app.models import ListB, SchTrat, ListM

class A(models.Model):
    data_create_a = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    data_modify_b = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    cant = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    days = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mod = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=MOD)
    sch = models.ForeignKey(SchTrat, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    list_m = models.ForeignKey(ListM, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class B(models.Model):
    data_create_b = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    data_modify_b = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TYPE)
    list_b = models.ForeignKey(ListaB, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    **med = models.ManyToManyField(A)**

class C(models.Model):
    data_create_c = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    data_modify_c = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    simpt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tens = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mm = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    temp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    height = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    glic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    AV = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    **person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)**
    admin = models.ForeignKey(Admin, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    **diag = models.ManyToManyField(B)**
```

I want in my template to add a new C(models.Model) an to  have posibility to insert multiple B(models.Model) and multiple A(models.Model) and to have posibiliy what i inserted in that new C(models.Model) before submit C(models.Model).

Thanks!

Comment: In terms of UI, selecting multiple B when creating C is easy: You just need a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` (form field) in your form, which Django does by default if you make a model form for C. The problem I see here is how to add multiple A's for each B you choose, since the relationship is A <-> B and not A <-> C. How do you want to do that just from a UI perspective? An inline formset inside an inline formset? Wouldn't it be easier to take it step by step and first associate B's, then in a different view, select the A's for each of the B's?

Comment: is very defficult for me to find a logic how to do it. i don t have enough knowledge

Comment: Yes, I understand it's difficult, but that was not my comment: Do you have any idea of how it would look like in the UI? In my opinion there isn't a good way to do this in one form/page. But if you have a mockup screenshot of how it should work, then that would help us give you an idea how to implement it.